# PHP Output Length Limited

Tags: php, output, size, response, limit

I have a problem in PHP, I'm using Nginx, PHP 5.6 and Laravel 5.4.
when page became large (not too large only more than 1500 lines, more or less!) page would not be loaded completely!
I checked and there were no PHP errors!
is there anything in php.ini or nginx conf to change and disable this limit?

Comment: update your question with screenshot of you problem

Comment: @LawrenceCherone turned on display error, there's no error!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone there's no error in PHP!